# Easiest way to join array PHP

Tags: php

I have these arrays and I want to combine them and create one array result.

```
$a[2][3][4][5] = Array('amt' => 20, 'comm' => 10);
$b[2][3]       = Array('amt' => 30, 'comm' => 20);
$c[2][3][4][6] = Array('amt' => 40, 'comm' => 30);
$d[2][3][7]    = Array('amt' => 50, 'comm' => 40);
```

I have tried to use `array_merge_recursive()` but had no luck.

My expected result is:

```
[2] => Array( 
    [3] => Array (
        [amt] => 30,
        [comm] => 20, 
        [4] => Array ( 
            [5] => Array(
                [amt] => 20,
                [comm] => 10
            ),
            [6] => Array(
                [amt] => 40,
                [comm] => 30
            ) 
        ),
        [7] => Array(
                [amt] => 50,
                [comm] => 40
            )
    )
)
```

I only want to want to merge all same keys and generate one combined result

Comment: What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: Welcome to SO; for us to help you better you need to provide at least the expected output, how the arrays should be combined and why what you have tried failed.

Comment: [2] => Array( [3] => Array (
                    [4] => Array (
                            [5] => Array([amt] => 20, [comm] => 10)
                            [6] => Array([amt] => 40, [comm] => 30)
   ),[amt] => 30, [comm] => 20
                    [7] => Array([amt] => 50, [comm] => 40
                )
        )

Comment: @user3782464 Please update the *question* with that kind of info.

Comment: my above comment is the expected result. i just want to merge the same key in the 4 arrays

Comment: I think some background explanation would help, right now I have no idea why you are even using these multidimensional arrays, and even your expected result seems completely unorganized.

Comment: You don't have a 'key' in there. The array position is not a key. To work with keys, use associative array like $array['mykeyname'] = array('amt'=>50)

Comment: @SvenSchneider the position is the key if one isn't declared. You can't have two 'amt' s in an array just like you cant have two items with position 0.

Comment: @JStephen Sure. But you can't merge based on a key that is basically the iterator. Sometimes the brevity of a comment omits the actual intention ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `array_merge_recursive()` you should use [`array_replace_recursive()`](http://php.net/array_replace_recursive):

```
$result = array_replace_recursive($a, $b, $c, $d);
```

In your case it behaves as if you replaced `$a` .. `$b` with `$result` for each assignment.

Comment: Thank you..you save my world

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell what you are using this for or why your arrays are setup that way, but I do not think there is a simple way to do what you want without writing your own code. Here are a few reasons.

1) Your arrays are not the same structure. for example to get the "comm" values out of arrays $a and $b you would use these variables:

```
$a[2][3][4][5]['comm']  //  equals 10
$b[2][3]['comm']        //  equals 20
```

2) If you were to merge them, the final array would be made up of arrays that have both values and more arrays. This is not a problem, but it definitely makes things much more complicated. Plus, usually when you have a hard time putting an array together, getting the data out of it can be just as difficult.

3) Again, its hard to tell what you are using it for, but would it be easier to just add each data array to the same single dimensional array? so the result would look like this:

```
Array (
    [0] = Array('amt' => 20, 'comm' => 10),
    [1] = Array('amt' => 30, 'comm' => 20),
    [2] = Array('amt' => 40, 'comm' => 30),
    [3] = Array('amt' => 50, 'comm' => 40)
)
```

If there is not any easier way of doing it then your best bet would be to make four loops inside each other (one for each of the array dimensions). Inside each loop figure out if the data is an array with more arrays, or if its an array with the values you want to add. If its the values then add them to the merged array, if its just another array then add an empty array and continue to the next loop. Its kinda hard to explain but writing it out would take me forever.